# An exception was raised during the creation of the specification: null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, specs2

I am trying to make a test case to test a function using specs2.

```
"Case 8: getHistograms" should {
    val correctOutput = "(2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)(1,0,1),(3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0)(1,0,1),"
    val arr = Array(Array("1", "2", "3"), Array("4","5","6"))
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr) 
    val header = Array("a","b","c")
    val skipCols = Array(0,1)
    val nBins = 3

      "return with correct output" in {
         val output = Util.getHistograms(rdd, header, skipCols, nBins)
         var str = ""
         for(i <-0 until output._1.length){
            str += "("+output._1(i).mkString(",")+")"+"("+output._2(i).mkString(",")+"),"
         }

        str must_== correctOutput
     }
  }
```

The `getHistogram` method is returning an output in this format:

```
(ArrayBuffer[Array[Double]], ArrayBuffer[Array[Long]])
```

The for loop is converting the output into String and it is being compared to `correctOutput` String.

I am getting the following exception when I try to execute this test:

```
org.specs2.specification.dsl.mutable.SpecificationCreationException: 
An exception was raised during the creation of the specification: null.
This means that you have some code which should be enclosed in an example. Instead of writing:

 "this is a block of examples" in {
   // set-up something
   createDatabase
   "first example" in { 1 must_== 1 }
   "second example" in { 1 must_== 1 }
 }

You should write:

 "this is a block of examples" in {
   "the setup must be ok" in {
     createDatabase must not(throwAn[Exception])
   }
   "first example" in { 1 must_== 1 }
   "second example" in { 1 must_== 1 }
 }

 Be careful because in the specification above the expectation might be that the
 database will be created before the "first" and "second" examples. This will NOT be the case
 unless you mark the specification as `sequential`. You can also have a look at the `BeforeEach/BeforeAll` traits
 to implement this kind of functionality.
```

There are other methods I am testing with the same syntax and they are working fine. I am not able to get why this exception is occurring with this method only. Please help.

UPDATE: Figured out that it is happening because of `sc.parallelize(arr)`. Can someone explain why this exception is being raised? Is there any way to test methods which take RDDs in parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala when you create a class you can add arbitrary code to the class body, `val`s for example:

```
class MyClass {
  val a = { sys.error("boom"); 1 }
}
```

This code gets executed when the class is instantiated. So if any expression throws an exception the class instantiation will fail and specs2 will not be able to report anything about your specification structure. You can generally prevent this by using `lazy val`s instead of `val`s:

```
class MyClass {
  lazy val arr = Array(Array("1", "2", "3"), Array("4","5","6"))
  lazy val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved. The problem was that

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
```

should have been written inside the inner block.

Correct code:

```
"Case 8: getHistograms" should {
    val correctOutput = "(2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)(1,0,1),(3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0)(1,0,1),"
    val arr = Array(Array("1", "2", "3"), Array("4","5","6")) 
    val header = Array("a","b","c")
    val skipCols = Array(0,1)
    val nBins = 3

      "return with correct output" in {
         val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
         val output = Util.getHistograms(rdd, header, skipCols, nBins)
         var str = ""
         for(i <-0 until output._1.length){
            str += "("+output._1(i).mkString(",")+")"+"("+output._2(i).mkString(",")+"),"
         }

        str must_== correctOutput
     }
  }
```

I still don't know why it is like that. Would be thankful if someone can help.